# failover nservicebus and quartz

Tags: nservicebus, quartz.net

**Context**

In our current setup of `Nservicebus` we have all our Projects configured to run on 2 machines as a failover.

In 1 project we have a `Quartz` scheduler configured to schedule some tasks.

One of those task is to send a message to `Nservicebus`.

But because this projects now runs on 2 machines, the message is post 2 times to the bus and handled twice.

**Question**

Is there a way to to configure in `Nservicebus` that only one instance of this project can be active at the same moment. And if 1 goes down, the other starts working?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the functional requirements of the message being sent? That can greatly help with finding the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be looking for a kind of load-balancing behavior. That is available via the distributed (if you're using MSMQ) as described here:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/

Please update your question if you're using a different transport (eg. RabbitMQ).